# A Confusion Regarding the Definitions of Operations Defined in a Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

On $\mathbb R^n$, define two operations
$$\alpha\oplus \beta=\alpha-\beta,$$
$$c.\alpha=-c\alpha$$

The operations on the right are the usual ones. Which of the axioms for a vector space are satisfied by $(\mathbb R^n,\oplus, . )$ ?

I am new to the concept of verctor spaces and I found this question from the book Linear Algebra (2nd Edition) by Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze in Chapter-2, 1st Excercise (Page no.-$34$) as Problem number $5.$

First of all, what is $\mathbb R^n$ ?

From my experience, I know that $\mathbb R^n$ generally denotes the set of all tuples of length $n$ in the set of real numbers, i.e $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n$ where $x_i\in \Bbb R.$

If this is the case, then the problem arises in the way they define the operations $\oplus$ and $\cdot $

It is mentioned that,
$$\alpha\oplus \beta=\alpha-\beta.$$

But what is meant by the thing $\alpha-\beta$. The problem is, it *might* be possible that $\alpha-\beta=\alpha+(-\beta)$, and this $\alpha+\beta$ may be defined as,( if $\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\beta=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$ ) $\alpha+\beta=(x_1+y_1,...,x_n+y_n)$ and $-\beta$ may be defined  as $\beta=(-y_1,-y_2,...,y_n)$ (,if $\beta=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$ ). But again, this was nowhere mentioned , these are just some of my thoughts based on previous exercises.

Same goes for $$c.\alpha=-c\alpha$$. The term, $-c\alpha$ again creates ambiguity. It seems it's possible that $-c\alpha=(-cx_1,-cx_2,\cdots,-cx_n)$  if $\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n).$ But again, it's nowhere given. It's just a thought of mine.

With these assumptions/thoughts/considerations, I solved the problem as follows:

First we check, that whether closure property is satisfied or not. If $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R^n,$ then, $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha-\beta.$ If $\alpha=(x_1,...,x_n), \beta=(y_1,...,y_n)$ then, $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha-\beta=(x_1-y_1,\cdots,x_n-y_n).$ Again, $x_i-y_i\in \mathbb F$ implies that $\alpha\oplus \beta\in \mathbb R^n.$

- So, closure property is satisfied.

Next, we check for commutative property. If $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R^n$ such that $\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\beta=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$ then, $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha-\beta=(x_1-y_1,\cdots,x_n-y_n)$ and $\beta\oplus\alpha=\beta-\alpha=(y_1-x_1,\cdots,y_n-x_n).$

So, $(x_1-y_1,\cdots,x_n-y_n)\neq (y_1-x_1,\cdots,y_n-x_n)$.

- Thus, the commutative property is not satisfied.

Now, we check for the associative property i.e if  $\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n),$$\beta=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$$\gamma=(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n)$, then, $\alpha-(\beta-\gamma)=(x_1-y_1+z_1,\cdots, x_n-y_n+z_n)$ and $(\alpha-\beta)-\gamma=(x_1-y_1-z_1,\cdots, x_n-y_n-z_n)$ and so, $\alpha-(\beta-\gamma)\neq (\alpha-\beta)-\gamma.$

- Thus, the associative property is not satisfied.

We note that $0\in \mathbb R^n$ and $0=\underbrace{(0,0,\cdots,0)}_{\text{n times}}$ and $\forall\alpha\in \mathbb R^n$ we have, $\alpha\oplus\alpha=0.$

Hence, we conclude that the identity and inverse property are satisfied.

Now, we come to the operation of multiplication.

If $1\in \mathbb F$, i.e $1$ is the unit element of $\mathbb F$ then $1.\alpha=-(1\alpha)=-\alpha$ and we have, $\alpha\neq -\alpha$ as, $-\alpha=(-x_1,-x_2,-x_3,...,-x_n)$ if $\alpha=(x_1,\cdots,x_n).$

- So, $1.\alpha\neq \alpha$

Now, we check $(c_1c_2).\alpha$ where $c_1,c_2$ are the scalars in $\mathbb F.$ We have, $(c_1c_2).\alpha=-(c_1c_2)\alpha=(-c_1c_2x_1,...,-c_1c_2x_n).$  Now, $c_1.(c_2.\alpha)=c_1(-c_2\alpha)=-(c_1(-c_2\alpha))=c_1c_2\alpha.$

- So, $(c_1c_2).\alpha\neq c_1.(c_2.\alpha)$

Now, we try to calculate the value of $c.(\alpha+\beta)$ (, where $c$ is a scalar in $\mathbb F$ and $\alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R^n$ where, $\alpha=(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\beta=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)$).  Now, $c.(\alpha+\beta) =-c(\alpha+\beta)=-c\beta-c\beta.$

Also, $c.\alpha+c.\beta=-c\alpha-c\beta.$

- Thus, $c.(\alpha+\beta)=c.\alpha+c.\beta$

We now try to compute $(c_1+c_2).\alpha.$ We have, $(c_1+c_2).\alpha=-(c_1+c_2)\alpha=-c_1\alpha-c_2\alpha.$

Also, $c_1.\alpha+c_2.\alpha=-c_1\alpha-c_2\alpha.$

- Finally, we have, $(c_1+c_2).\alpha=c_1.\alpha+c_2.\alpha$

---

Is my above solution based on the assumptions, correct/valid?

Comment: It's clear we still get all the same scalar multiples (since $c \in \mathbb K$ iff $-c$ is for whatever field by definition) and thus $-\beta$ is defined. The exercise wants you to go through the list of axioms for a vector space and see if these operations define one.

Comment: When you say it was "nowhere" mentioned, if they wrote "The operations on the right are the usual ones," that's where it was mentioned. If you wrote it, it is a natural inference for somebody to make, but without the entire textbook in front of me, I can't say more about why it isn't in the book, or where it would be found there

Comment: What would $0 \oplus x $ be and what axiom would this contradict? There is no shortcut to just grinding through the axioms until one fails.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, but I am asking about the meaning not the solution?

Comment: You are overthinking this.

Comment: I don't know if this question has multiple question on one post or not. But I genuinely feel that it wouldn't be a good thing to open multiple questions or threads of these same sort as this will surely clutter things up for me and the site as well (, not to forget).

Comment: $R$ is defined on p.2. $F^n$ for a general field $F$ is defined on p.29. The usual addition and scalar multiplication of members of $F^n$ as well as the meaning of $-\alpha$ for a vector $\alpha$ are also defined on the same page. The said exercise appears on p.34. To be fair, the authors indeed have not explained that $\alpha-\beta$ means $\alpha+(-\beta)$, but I think almost everyone understands its meaning at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of your answer looks fine. There are some issues about the second half.

Your disproof of $(c_1c_2)\cdot\alpha=c_1\cdot(c_2\cdot\alpha)$ is essentially correct, but there is a missing dot in the step $c_1\cdot(c_2\cdot\alpha)=c_1\color{red}{\cdot}(-c_2\alpha)$.

Your inspections of the two distributive axioms are incorrect. What you should verify are $c\cdot(\alpha\oplus\beta)=(c\cdot\alpha)\oplus (c\cdot\beta)$ and $(c_1+c_2)\alpha=(c_1\alpha)\oplus(c_2\alpha)$, but you have mistaken them as $c\cdot(\alpha\color{red}{+}\beta)=(c\cdot\alpha)\color{red}{+}(c\cdot\beta)$ and $(c_1+c_2)\alpha=(c_1\alpha)\color{red}{+}(c_2\alpha)$.

Comment: Ok, but the thing is, we might not think of $-\alpha$ to be an inverse of $\alpha$ for, the inverse of $\alpha$ is $\alpha$, isn't it? So, we should **NOT** interpret it like, "$\alpha$ is an element of $R^n$ and inverse of inverse of an element is the element itself i.e $-(-\alpha)=\alpha$." Isnt it?

Comment: Does, $-\alpha$ denote, the inverse of $\alpha$  for in the book, at the definition  of a vector space it's written that if $0$ is an identity element of $V$ then, $\forall \alpha$ $\exists -\alpha\in V$ such that $\alpha+(-\alpha)=0$ . The other meaning of $-\alpha$ maybe $(-x_1,...,-x_n)$ if, $\alpha=(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: @user1511 Ok, so there are two $-\alpha$ 's in the story? One $-\alpha$ is the inverse of $\alpha$ and the other one is $-\alpha=(-a_1,-a_2,...,-a_n)$ where$\alpha=(a_1,...,a_n)$ ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley Yes. You may denote the additive inverse of $\alpha$ with respect to $\oplus$ as $\ominus\alpha$. In defining $c\cdot\alpha=-c\alpha$, the authors have explicitly stated that the operations on the right are the usual ones in $R^n$. So, they mean the usual inverse of $c\alpha$, not $\ominus(c\alpha)$.

Comment: But in $c.(\alpha)\oplus c.\beta=-c\alpha-(-c\beta)$ here, $-(-c\beta)$ to be interpreted as follows: In $-\color{red}{(-c\beta)}$ the $\color{red}{(-c\beta)}$ is $(-cb_1,...,-cb_n)$ and then $-(-c\beta)$ as again, $(cb_1,cb_2,...,cb_n)$ ,right?

Comment: Ok, then what is the $-$ sign indicating in $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha-\beta$. Is it indicating, $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha+(-\beta)$ . Here, $-\beta$ is nothing but the inverse of $\beta$ under $+$ and not $\oplus$ ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley Yes. As mentioned in the book and a number of times in my (now deleted) comments, all operations on the right of the defining equalities $\alpha\oplus\beta=\alpha-\beta$ and $c\cdot\alpha=-c\alpha$ are the usual ones in $R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that you're overthinking matters.

Assuming $R$ denotes the real numbers, then we answer your questions in turn:

- $R^n$ indeed refers to the collection of $n$-tuples of real numbers, i.e.
  $$
  R^n := \{ (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \mid x_1,\cdots,x_n \in R \}
  $$
  (I like to adopt the shorthand $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ for $(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, and will continue using it from here on out.)
- We define several standard operations on it: given that $c \in R$ and $x,y \in R^n$, with $x := (x_i)_{i=1}^n, y := (y_i)_{i=1}^n$, we have
  $$
  x+y := (x_i+y_i)_{i=1}^n 
  \qquad
  cx := (cx_i)_{i=1}^n
  $$
  One may deduce in turn that
  $$
  x-y = x+(-y) = (x_i - y_i)_{i=1}^n
  $$
  and
  $$
  -cx = (-cx_i)_{i=1}^n
  $$

I also feel the need to note that these are discussed in Example $1$ of Section $2.1$ of your textbook (on page $29$). (Note that the real numbers form a field. The addition and field multiplication used there are those inherited from the field in question.)

Comment: I have edited my post. Mind taking a look at it?